# game background file of just 2KB ...how?

Tags: graphics

I am making game for mobile phone and i have little knowledge of creating graphics for games. I am making graphics using CorelDraw & Photoshop.

I made flash.png using above 2 software's & could squeeze the size to 47Kb only.....

But I came across one game which has file size just 2kb for its background (bg0 & bg1.png)

I want to know how do I make such beautiful graphics without increasing the size of my file...

I assume the gamer must have hand sketched, scanned & used one of the above software's to fill the colors.....but i am not sure about it...

plz help

Comment: I know many possible reasons. But you don't know SO's FAQ.

Comment: P.s. it might also increase your rep, so you can actually post the images you're talking about.

Comment: Also, what are the dimensions / color depths of the images involved?

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to reduce the size of a PNG:

1. Reduce the colour depth. Don't use RGB true/24 bit colour, use an indexed colour image. You need to add a palette to the image, but each pixel is one byte, not two.
2. Once you have an indexed colour image, reduce the number of colours in the palette. There is a limit to how many colours you can reduce it by - the fewer colours, the lower the image quality.
3. Remove unnecessary PNG chunks. Art packages may add additional data to the PNG that isn't image data (creation date, author info, resolution, comments, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Check http://pmt.sourceforge.net/pngcrush/ to get rid of unneeded PNG chunks and compress the IDAT chunk even further. This might help a lot or not at all depending on the PNG that came out of the art packages. If it doesn't help, consider index PNGs. And if you go for paletized PNGs be sure to check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_cycling for cool effects you might be able to use.

Answer (score 0):

Use a paletted png with few colors and then pass the png through a png optimizer like the free exe [PngOptimizer](http://psydk.org/PngOptimizer.php)

If your png still is too big reduce the number of colors used and reoptimize. Rince and repeat ^^.

I have used this technique on quite a lot of mobile games where size was of the essence.